# Toolbar at the bottom of the screen

Tags: position, toolbar, windows-8

In IE in Windows 8, the toolbar/addressbar in Internet Explorer is at the bottom of the screen.  Is there any research or study that supports this kind of layout?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's likely this is targeting touch devices where you want to have the entry area nearer to you for easier finger typing, and so that when entering a url (should you need to actually type!) your hands are not covering and obscuring the rest of the screen.

This is also hinted at by the design of the buttons which are well designed for fingers...